# How Do You Use Logging and Tkinter Module Together

Tags: python-3.x, logging, tkinter

I'm trying logging for the first time and am able to get it to work correctly outside of my app using a very simple example.

```
import logging
import datetime

logging.basicConfig(
    filename='%s%s%s.log' % ("test_", "whatever_", str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%y_%m_%d_%H_%M")) + "_"), level=logging.DEBUG) 
def move_along(param):
    n1, n2 = param
    logging.info("%s and %s equal an even number!" % (n1, n2))
    print("does this happen?")

def add(n1, n2):
    try:
        total = n1 + n2
        if total % 2 == 0:
            param = []
            param.append(n1)
            param.append(n2)
            move_along(param)
    except Exception:
        logging.error("add | ", exc_info=True)  
    else:
        print("Sorry, %s and %s do not equal an even number..." % (n1, n2)) 

add(2,'a')
```

My main app is much bigger and runs on a mainloop(). If I want a log file to be created every time an unchecked exception is triggered or the app is closed how do I do this? At the moment I cannot even get the log file to be generated on my desktop unlike with my simple example.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I'm a moron. 
"At the moment I cannot even get the log file to be generated on my desktop unlike with my simple example."

That's because the location of my python app file is NOT on my desktop. Bottomline, my log files where being created just not where I thought that they would be because I hadn't specified that I wanted them to go to my desktop. All is well.